# How to download excel file to a specific folder in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, excel, path

I need to download the excel to the specific folder

Example : D:\email

Now i was able to download the excel file in downloads ....but i need to download in D:\email

this is my code to create excel file :

```
             protected void UploadDataTableToExcel(DataTable dtRecords)
       {
        string XlsPath = Server.MapPath(@"~/Add_data/test.xls");
        string attachment = string.Empty;
        if (XlsPath.IndexOf("\\") != -1)
        {
            string[] strFileName = XlsPath.Split(new char[] { '\\' });
            attachment = "attachment; filename=" + strFileName[strFileName.Length - 1];
        }
        else
            attachment = "attachment; filename=" + XlsPath;
        try
        {
            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
            string tab = string.Empty;

            foreach (DataColumn datacol in dtRecords.Columns)
            {
                Response.Write(tab + datacol.ColumnName);
                tab = "\t";
            }
            Response.Write("\n");

            foreach (DataRow dr in dtRecords.Rows)
            {
                tab = "";
                for (int j = 0; j < dtRecords.Columns.Count; j++)
                {
                    Response.Write(tab + Convert.ToString(dr[j]));
                    tab = "\t";
                }

                Response.Write("\n");
            }
            Response.End();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Response.Write(ex.Message);
        }
            }
```

Comment: where are you able to download it right now?

Comment: I was able download in "Downloads"

Comment: sent u a solution if it works for you !

Answer (score 0):

you can manually move the file after download using

```
string sourceFile = @"C:\Users\test\Documents\Downloads\test.xls";
string destinationFile = @"D:\emails\test.xls";
// To move a file or folder to a new location:
System.IO.File.Move(sourceFile, destinationFile);
```